# react checkbox put method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I'm new to react and I'm having trouble creating a function that would fire when a checkbox is selected within a table, so this function would take the table id and update that field via put and update the screen again.

how did you manage to do that?

```js
import React from 'react'
import Main from '../template/main'

import axios from 'axios'

const headerProps = {
  icon: 'users',
  title: 'Controle Presença Alunos',

}

const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8000/Presenca/'
const initState = {
  user: {
    id: '',
    Aluno_nome: '',
    Aula_descricao: '',
    status: '',
    Alunos: '',
    Aulas: ''
  },
  list: []
}

export default class Aluno_presenca extends React.Component {

  state = { ...initState
  }

  /**Chamada quando o elemento for exibido na tela */
  async componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(baseUrl, {
        crossdomain: true
      })
      .then(resp => {
        this.setState({
          list: resp.data
        }) /**salvamos dentro da lista as requisições */

      })
  }


**tente criar esse motodo para salvar mas preciso pega os valores do estado atual**
  update() {
    axios.put(`${baseUrl}/${user.id}`, {
        id: 314,
        Aluno_nome: 'Jose',
        Aula_descricao: 'história',
        status: 'True',
        Alunos: 1,
        Aulas: 1
      })
      .then(function(response) {


        this.componentDidMount

      });
  }



  renderForm() {
    /**jsx que ira renderizar o formulário */
    return ( <
      div >



      <
      /div>
    );
  }


  /**edição */
  load(user) {
    this.setState({
      user
    }) /**atualiza o estado da aplicação. */
  }
  remove(user) {
    axios.delete(`${baseUrl}/${user.id}`)
      .then(resp => {
        const list = this.state.list.filter(u => u !== user)
        this.setState({
          list
        })
      })
  }



  /**list users */
  rendertable() {
    return ( <
      table className = "table mt-4" >
      <
      thead >
      <
      tr >
      <
      th > ID < /th> <
      th > NOME < /th> <
      th > Materia < /th> <
      th > Presenca < /th> <
      th > aluno < /th> <
      th > aula < /th> < /
      tr > <
      /thead> <
      tbody > {
        this.renderows()
      } <
      /tbody>             < /
      table >
    );
  }



  checked = e => {
    const checked = e.target.checked;
    const name = e.target.name;
    this.setState({
      [name]: checked
    });
  };



  renderows() {
    /**mapeando dados que estão no estado do objeto */
    return this.state.list.map((user, index) => {
        return ( <
            tr key = {
              index
            } >
            <
            td > {
              user.id
            } < /td> <
            td > {
              user.Aluno_nome
            } < /td> <
            td > {
              user.Aula_descricao
            } < /td> <
            td >
            <
            input type = "checkbox"

            id = {
              user.id
            }

            name = "elem"
            checked = {
              this.state.checked
            }
            onChange = {
              this.save_click
            }



            /> {
            String(this.state.checked)
          }

          <
          /td> <
        td > {
          user.Aluno
        } < /td> <
        td > {
            user.Aulas
          } < /td> < /
          tr >
      );
    })
}



render() {
  return ( <
    Main { ...headerProps
    } >

    {
      this.renderForm()
    } {
      this.rendertable()
    }

    <
    /Main>
  );
}
}
```

Comment: What is exactly your problem is? Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

ok, so first of all, try to use prettier or any code formatter, it was really hard to me to try to read your code, as i couldn't understand your code i'll tell you how to do it from scratch:

on the checkbox, add a function that fires when the onChange event is called, that function should use send the put request wherever you want, after that send a get request to get the new data and call and do a setState with the updated data, that should be all you need

tell me if i got something wrong or you have any questions, happy to help :)

should be something like this:

```
save_click(){
    axios.put(`${baseUrl}352/`, {
        id : this.state.id,
        Aluno_nome: this.state.Aluno_nome, 
        Aula_descricao: this.state.Aula_descricao, 
        status: this.state.status, 
        Alunos: this.state.Alunos,
        Aulas: this.state.Aulas
    })
    .then(resp => {
          console.log('salvo com sucesso')
          console.log(resp.data)
        });
```

or even easier

```
save_click(){
    axios.put(`${baseUrl}352/`, {...this.state})
    .then(resp => {
          console.log('salvo com sucesso')
          console.log(resp.data)
        });
```

Comment: my biggest difficulty is getting passes the parameters in the save_click. Passing fixed value is working normally.

Comment: Thank you! you save my life.

Answer (score 0):

I created the save_click method

```js
  save_click(
        )
        {axios.put(`${baseUrl}352/`, {  id :352, Aluno_nome: 'Matheus', Aula_descricao: 'história', status: 'False', Alunos: 1,Aulas:1 })
        .then(resp => {
          console.log('salvo com sucesso')
          console.log(resp.data)
         

        });  }




my biggest difficulty is getting passes the parameters in the save_click. Passing fixed value is working normally.

  <input type="checkbox" 
                
                id={user.id}
              
                name="elem"
                value={user.status }
                onChange={this.save_click}
/>



renderows(){
   *mapping data that is in the state of the object
    return this.state.list.map((user,index) => {
        return (                
            <tr key={index}>
                <td>{user.id}</td>
                <td>{user.Aluno_nome}</td>
                <td>{user.Aula_descricao}</td>
                <td>
                <input type="checkbox" 
                
                id={user.id}
              
                name="elem"
                value={user.status }
                onChange={this.save_click}
                           
                           
                            
                            />
                         
                      
                </td>
                <td>{user.Aluno}</td>
                <td>{user.Aulas}</td>
            </tr>
        );
    })
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmiT0.png)